# asp.net-core / c# - check if a row exists in a table that has 2 primary keys?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-core

This is my table schema in Microsoft SQL db:

```
[account_id](PK, FK, int, not null)
[business_id](PK, FK, int, not null)
[identifier](nvarchar(100), null)
```

Before adding a new row into this table, I want to check if a row exists that has the same values in two primary keys. For example I have a table:

```
account_id | business_id | identifier 
_____________________________________    
         1 |           2 | abc
         2 |           3 | cdf
```

Now I try different cases:

```
context.add(account_id: 1, business_id: 3, identifier: null) => success
context.add(account_id: 1, business_id: 2, identifier: null) => fail
context.add(account_id: 2, business_id: 2, identifier: null) => success
context.add(account_id: 3, business_id: 3, identifier: null) => success
```

In short, I want to check if a row already exists with two same primary keys as `account_id` and `business_id`, otherwise, create a new row.

This is my code without checking duplicates yet:

```
[HttpPost("generate-identifier")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(void), 204)]
public IActionResult GenerateIdentifier(GenerateIdentifierRequest model)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest(GetValidationErrors(ModelState));

  BusinessAccount businessAccount = new BusinessAccount() {
    AccountId = GetCurrentUserId(),
    BusinessId = model.BusinessId,
    Identifier = model.Identifier
  };

  context.Add(businessAccount);
  context.SaveChanges();

  return NoContent();
}
```

Comment: Surely that's a table with a composite primary key? I'm pretty sure you can't have multiple _primary_ keys?

Comment: Are you using EntityFramework?

Comment: @john: yep, it's kind of composite primary key, then it's possible to have multiple, and this is an actual table I have in my db now. Yes, I use EF too.

Comment: A table can only have one primary key. (However, alternate keys are possible.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having two or more primary keys is called composite key. However, you cannot use the Key attribute to define composite keys. This can only be done via the Fluent API. But it seems your already managed this first part.

For second part to check if the record is available or not you can normally use a linq query using .Any() or .Count

ex :

```
var businessAccountCount = context.BusinessAccount.Count(a => a.AccountId == .. && a.business_id == ..);
if(businessAccountCount > 0)
   return ....
else
 {
    //Add your Entity & Return Created
 }
```

Comment: great, try and tell me

Comment: the `var businessAccountCount` shows error `Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'int'`

Comment: sorry it should be  == will update it, appologise wrong type

Comment: Should be _Having two or more columns in a primary key is called composite key_.

Comment: in a primary key or as a primary key ?

Comment: I think I have an issue with my db configuration that return this error when adding a row: `The property 'BusinessId' on entity type 'BusinessAccount' has a temporary value. Either set a permanent value explicitly or ensure that the database is configured to generate values for this property.`

Comment: did you define BusinessId as a foreign key also ? if yes be sure that the value assigned has matching value in the BusinessAccount table

Comment: yes, both `account_id` and `business_id` are foreign keys from table `dbo.account` and `dbo.business` respectively, it's so weird I got this error, I need to figure it out first.

Comment: be sure that both ids are available in their tables.